# Elementwise operations on very large matrices in R

Tags: r, bigdata

I have a "big data" problem right now. I have 10000 matrices, each of which is about 10000x10000 elements and has named dimensions. They are currently stored in groups of 100 R objects, each of which is 16GB in size and is a list of 100 matrices. I would like to do the following:

1. Sort each matrix according to the dimension names of the first matrix.
2. Calculate elementwise summary statistics (mean, median, some quantiles) on the list of matrices. Each summary stat will return a 10000x10000 matrix.

If the matrices were smaller, I could do it this way:

```
load('distmat1.r') # loads list called ericsondist with 100 matrices.
roworder <- dimnames(ericsondist[[1]])[[1]] # get sorting order.
ericsondist <- lapply(ericsondist, function(x) x[roworder, roworder]) # sort the list of matrices.
distlist <- ericsondist

# Load the rest of the matrices, sort them, and concatenate.
for (i in 2:100) {
  load(paste0('distmat',i,'.r'))
  ericsondist <- lapply(ericsondist, function(x) x[roworder, roworder])
  distlist <- c(distlist, ericsondist)
}

ericsondist <- abind::abind(ericsondist, along = 3) # bind to an array.

# Mean and upper and lower quantile of matrices, elementwise.
ericsondistmean <- apply(ericsondist, 1:2, mean)
ericsondistlower <- apply(ericsondist, 1:2, quantile, probs = 0.025)
ericsondistupper <- apply(ericsondist, 1:2, quantile, probs = 0.975)
```

However, although I have access to a lot of RAM, that will clearly cause an overflow since all the matrices are >1TB when stored on the hard disk. Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can do these calculations while minimizing the amount of RAM used?

Comment: Since the summary stats are element-wise, you could compute these stats e.g. row by row. Sort the matrices ahead of time. Only load one row of data from each sorted matrix into RAM at a time. Then loop.

Comment: No, they are pairwise distance matrices so there aren't any zeroes.